# CakePHP broken after editing core.php

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm woking on a project that is using an older version of cakePHP, the config file says 1.1.18.5850.

I was initially having trouble with my routing, only my index "/" route worked, everything else broke. In order to see what was happening I changed the following line in core.php file

```
define('DEBUG',2);
```

at which point everything stopped working. I tried setting it back to 0, but that didn't work.

Right now, it appears to be sending me a view named default, which on throws a fatal error. I fixed the error, but all I see is blank screen, none of the content loads.

The route it should be accessing is

```
$Route->connect('/', array('controller' => 'schools', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Which in turn goes to the schools controller

```
function login() {
        if($this->is_logged==='true') {
            if($this->is_admin==='true') {
                $this->redirect('/admin/');
                exit;
            } elseif(!empty($this->school_info)){   
                $this->redirect('schools/welcome?page');
                exit;
            } 
            elseif(!empty($this->owner_info)){  
                $this->redirect('schools/welcome?page');
                exit;
            } 
        }
        if(!empty($this->params['form'])) {
            $email = $this->clean->go($this->params['form']['username']);
            $password = $this->clean->go($this->params['form']['password']);
            $encrypted = md5($password);

            $owner = $this->Owner->find("`Owner`.`email` = '$email' AND `Owner`.`password` = '$encrypted'");
            $user = $this->User->find("`User`.`email` = '$email' AND `User`.`password` = '$encrypted' AND `User`.`removed` = 0");

            if(!empty($owner)) {
                $this->_writeAuth($owner['Owner']['email'],$owner['Owner']['password']);
                $this->redirect('schools/welcome?page');
                exit;
            }elseif(!empty($user)&&$user['User']['user_type']==='Admin')
            {
                $email = $this->clean->go($this->params['form']['username']);
                $password = $this->clean->go($this->params['form']['password']);
                $encrypted = $this->User->encode($password);

                //$user = $this->User->find("`User`.`email` = '$email' AND `User`.`password` = '$encrypted' AND `User`.`removed` = 0");
                if(!empty($user)) {
                    $this->_writeAuth($user['User']['email'], $user['User']['password']);
                    $this->redirect('/admin/');
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else 
            {   
                $this->flashErrorAndGo('Invalid username or password.');
                $this->redirect('schools/login/');
                exit;
            }
        }
        //$this->render('login','login');
    }
```

I've tried just doing

```
function login() {die;}
```

but it doesn't do anything, and still renders the view "default"

I'm not too familiar with cake, so I've been scratching my head trying to figure out what happened. Everything was working fine until I made the change in core.php, but I changed it back so I don't know why the issue continues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the log files, both the CakePHP logs and your server ones? I suspect that you'll find error messages in the server logs. It would also be worth checking the syntax of core.php to make sure you've not broken something (`php -l`). Hopefully you're using some form of version control and could revert back to a working version?

Comment: Tried cleaning your cakephp cache with clearCache()?